# How to decode base64 to the original file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am working on one project where i need to upload file (pdf,rar or any type ) from client to postgres database so I converted the file to base64 string
now I need the user to be able to download the file again so how I can convert the base64 to the original file in the user side
Thanks  alot

Comment: Presumably by reversing the operations you did when encoding the file.

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Then you might have to debug it.